# Can we have multiple targets in K8s Horizontal Pod Autoscaler?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

We are considering to use HPA to scale number of pods in our cluster. This is how a typical HPA object would like:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: hpa-demo
 namespace: default
spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   name: hpa-deployment
 minReplicas: 1
 maxReplicas: 10
 targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 20
```

My question is - can we have multiple targets (scaleTargetRef) for HPA? Or each deployment/RS/SS/etc. has to have its own HPA?

Tried to look into K8s doc, but could not find any info on this. Any help appreciated, thanks.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-metrics-apis

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/

Answer (score 3):

`Can we have multiple targets (scaleTargetRef) for HPA ?`

One `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` has only one `scaleTargetRef` that hold one referred resource only.

Comment: yea its not array (-), thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

HorizontalPodAutoscaler controls the scale of a *single* resource - Deployment/StatefulSet/ReplicaSet. It is actually stated in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work), though not that directly:

> [image: HorizontalPodAutoscaler controls the scale of a Deployment and its ReplicaSet]

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/horizontal-pod-autoscaler-v1/) there is a reference to it as well - single target resource is defined by the `scaleTargetRef`, horizontal pod autoscaler learns the current resource consumption for it and will set the desired number of pods by using its Scale subresource.

From practical experience, reference for multiple workload resources in a single `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` definition will work for only one of them. In addition, when applying  `kubectl autoscale` command with several resources to create a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object, separate `hpa` object will be created for each of them.